# Prove that $e^x$ is continuous in $(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

It seems like there are multiple ways to do this but I am most interested in showing that for every $n\in\mathbb{R}, n>0$ there exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $e^x=n$. If I let $x= \ln n$, isn't this obviously true? I think I am missing the point of the exercise.

Using the definition  $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n$

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: but for every $n\in\mathbb{R}, n>0$, there also exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tan(x)=n$, but $\tan(x)$ isn't necessarily continuous.

Comment: @ASKASK $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^x$

Comment: Check the definition of continuity.

Comment: @Macavity I want to show for every $n\in R$ there exists $x\in R$ such that $e^x=n$ Using real analysis definition of continuous I guess

Comment: I really want to help.  So, please let me know if there is any way I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

We need to show that for all $\epsilon>0$, we can find a number $\delta $ such that $|e^{x+\Delta x}-e^x|<\epsilon$, whenever $|\Delta x|<\delta$.  To that end,

$$\begin{align}
|e^{x+\Delta x}-e^x|&=e^x|e^{\Delta x}-1|\\
&\le e^x\left|\frac{1}{1-\Delta x}-1\right|\\
&=e^x\left|\frac{\Delta x}{1-\Delta x}\right|
\end{align}$$

where we used the fact that $e^{-x}>1-x$; this can be shown from the given definition for $e^x$.

If we first choose $\delta \le \frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{1}{1-\Delta x}<2$ when $|\Delta x|<\delta$.  Thus, given $\epsilon>0$,

$$|e^{x+\Delta x}-e^x|= e^x\left|\frac{\Delta x}{1-\Delta x}\right|\le2e^x|\Delta x|<\epsilon$$

whenever $|\Delta x|<\frac12 e^{-x}\epsilon$.  We then choose $\delta = \frac12 \text{min}(1,e^{-x}\epsilon)$ and we are done!

Comment: Is $\Delta$ the metric ?

Comment: @grayQuant, $\Delta x$ is a difference between two $x$-values.